# Wireless-AC 9560 - Connection is slower on Ubuntu 20.04 than on Windows

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I have laptop Asus Zenbook Pro 15 dualboot with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10. I have checked that when I am using my computer with Windows, my wireless connection is faster and the signal shows stronger than when I use Ubuntu.

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network                 
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 14.3
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:14.3
       nombre lógico: wlo1
       versión: 10
       serie: d0:c6:37:f8:23:48
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-59-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:16 memoria:e531c000-e531ffff
```

From the output above, I am using the `iwlwifi` driver. Anyone knows if I can improve my WiFi connection if I use a different driver? If that's not the case, is there any configuration which I could try in order to fix it?

EDIT:

**ip link**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:c6:37:f8:23:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:97:91:0e:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**nmcli device wifi list**

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                             MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        3C:84:6A:CD:41:E2  MiFibra-1B0A_EXT                 Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        D8:32:14:7B:CD:F9  Nova                             Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
*       3C:84:6A:CD:41:E1  MiFibra-1B0A_EXT                 Infra  100   135 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        80:78:71:5B:36:FF  MOVISTAR_36F0                    Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        10:62:E5:BF:3C:7B  DIRECT-76-HP OfficeJet Pro 8710  Infra  10    65 Mbit/s   44      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        F8:8E:85:CE:DF:37  MOVISTAR_DF36                    Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  WPA1      
        30:B1:B5:07:1B:0C  MiFibra-1B0A                     Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        68:FF:7B:C2:A9:21  MOVISTAR_CD78_EXT                Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        68:FF:7B:C2:A9:22  MOVISTAR_CD78_5GEXT              Infra  36    135 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        94:6A:B0:3C:FE:BA  MiFibra-FEB8                     Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  39      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        34:57:60:DF:38:34  MOVISTAR_3832                    Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        4C:D1:A1:FB:0E:48  HUAWEI P20 Pro                   Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        D8:32:14:7B:CD:F1  Nova                             Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        4C:1B:86:3D:50:B6  MiFibra-50B4                     Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        E4:AB:89:37:AA:66  MOVISTAR_AA65                    Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        D8:32:14:7B:CD:FC  Nova                             Infra  40    270 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        B2:5C:DA:53:7E:7D  DIRECT-7D-HP ENVY Photo 6200     Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA2      
        0C:80:63:59:CF:58  vodafoneE638                     Infra  1     405 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        94:6A:B0:3C:FE:BB  --                               Infra  108   540 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA2      
        CC:ED:DC:5A:0E:47  Casa Maria Antonietta            Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA2      
        FE:EC:DA:B7:48:0A  --                               Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA2      
        86:78:71:5B:36:FE  MOVISTAR_36F0                    Infra  104   540 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA2      
        80:78:71:5B:36:FE  MOVISTAR_PLUS_36F0               Infra  104   540 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA2      
        62:6A:B0:3C:FE:B8  MiFibra-FEB8                     Infra  108   540 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA2      
        4C:6E:6E:BE:05:40  MIWIFI_5G_w53R                   Infra  112   405 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA2      
        98:97:D1:46:F3:03  MOVISTAR_F302                    Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2      
        6A:B1:B5:07:1B:0E  MiFibra-1B0A                     Infra  100   540 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2      
        30:B1:B5:07:1B:0D  --                               Infra  100   540 Mbit/s  20      ▂___  WPA2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: @chili555 Edited, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSID to which you are connected is this:

> MiFibra-1B0A_EXT                 Infra  100   135 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__
> WPA2

If you have administrative privileges for the router, please check its settings. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.

I recommend a fixed channel rather than automatic channel selection. I notice, in your readings, that there are several other 5 gHz SSIDs and at least two others are also on channel 100. I recommend that you select a channel far away from others nearby.

You can find out what channels your wireless device supports with a terminal command:

```
iwlist freq
```

Then compare the channels available in the router and select one other than those in your readings.

Next, our wireless may be dropping or slow because of power management; that is, the feature where the card partially powers down to save battery power during periods of inactivity and then, ideally, powers back up seamlessly when activity resumes. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

After making changes in the router, reboot it by power cycling.